# Python 3 Beginner

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to get this small code to work. The only thing that happens when I execute it, is the cmd prompt says press enter to close. How can I get the rest of the script to run and show? I am in a beginners class for school. This doesn't need to be super over simplified. For the most part, it's just 3 rooms and I need to be able to move back and forth through the 3 rooms and that's all.

```
# A dictionary for the simplified dragon text game
# The dictionary links a room to other rooms.
rooms = {
    'Great Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom'},
    'Bedroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'},
    'Cellar': {'West': 'Bedroom'}
}


def movebetweenrooms(player, direction):
    """
    Returns the new player state after moving into another room
    """

    current_room = player

    # check if there is a room in the specified direction
    if direction in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = rooms[current_room][direction]

    # error handling
    else:
        print("There is nothing in that direction!")

    # return the player state
        return current_room


def displayinstructions():
    """
    display the starting instructions
    """

    print("Simplified Dragon Text Game\n\n"
          "Collect 6 items to win the game, or be killed by the Dragon.\n"
          "Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West\n")


def main():
    displayinstructions()
    player = ("Great Hall", [])

    while True:

        current_room = player

        # Player info
        # -----------
        print(f"\nYou are in the {current_room}")

        # Game ending
        # -----------
        if player[0] == "Cellar":

            if len(player[1]) == 0:
                print(f"Congratulations! You have defeated the Dragon!")
            else:
                print("NOM NOM...GAME OVER!")

            # greeting and exiting
            print("Thanks for playing the game. Hope you enjoyed it.")
            break

        # input validation and parsing
        # ----------------------------
        # get the player's move
        print("-" * 35)
        move = input("Enter your move:\n")

        # invalid move syntax
        if " " not in move:
            print("Invalid input!")
            continue

        # split the move into an action and an argument
        action, arg = move.split(" ", 1)

        # move into another room
        if action == "go":
            movebetweenrooms(player, arg)

        # invalid action
        else:
            print("Invalid input!")


input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. *Beginner* is irrelevant, and *python 3* is clear from the tag you added. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to be of use to a future site user who is scanning a list of search results trying to find a solution to their problem. Thanks.

Comment: Please also take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), 
and condense your code down to a [mre]. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Where do you call `main()`? Do you think anything should happen if you do not call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main` function is not automatically executed in python.

If you want it to run add this to the end of your script:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much.